# Python function doesn't work

Tags: python, function

I'm learning Python, and I am up to the chapter on functions, and I wrote code for one:

```
import random

def roll(sides, dice):
    result = 0
    for rolls in range(0,dice):
        result += random.randint(1, sides)
    return result
```

but, when I try to enter the function, this comes up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    roll ()
TypeError: roll() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: "I am up to the chapter on functions" in what book?

Comment: Go through your code line by line. What did you think was going to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put in numbers between the (). Like roll(3, 1)

Answer (score 5):

Your function expects two arguments.  You need to pass a value for `sides` and another one for `dice`.

Thus, an example of a proper call to your function would look like this:

```
roll(1,3)
```

Of course, sometimes you want your function to have default arguments.  In other words, you want to be able to call your function *without* any explicit arguments.  To do this, you add the default value for the argument in your function definition.  Let's suppose you want the function to act like a normal die by default.  All you need to do is this:

```
def roll(sides = 6, dice = 1)
```

With this function, a call such as `roll()`, will assume you're passing 6 and 1 as arguments.  Of course, you can always call your function *with* arguments and it'll override the defaults.

**TL;DR:**  Either pass arguments, define default arguments, or both.

Answer (score 1):

The function expects two arguments, as in

```
twoDice = roll(6, 2)
```

or

```
nineCoinFlips = roll(2, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> def roll(sides, dice):
...     result = 0
...     for rolls in range(0,dice):
...         result += random.randint(1, sides)
...     return result
... 
>>> roll(6, 8)
23
```

you could also set defaults:

```
>>> import random
>>> def roll(sides = 6, dice = 2):
...     result = 0
...     for rolls in range(0,dice):
...         result += random.randint(1, sides)
...     return result
... 
>>> roll()
10
```